# Regarding jvm termination when main method terminates

Tags: java

In an interview there was a question was being asked from me...

```
The JVM exits when  ‘main ()’ method reaches its end.
(Circle ONE choice)

Always true 
Not necessarily 
Always false    
None of the above
```

what i have answered to this question is Not necessarily , please advise is it the correct approach.

Comment: Why did you answer "Not necessarily" ? What was your reasoning?

Comment: You can simply google it lot of theads explains it .

Answer (score 2):

`Not necessarily`

Depends on the Non demons threads present in your program.
`main()` is a non-demon thread.

For example you have 3 non-demon threads `t1`, `t2`, and `main()`.
For the completion of your program, all these threads are required to be completed or terminated.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `Not necessarily`. The JVM terminates when *all non-daemon* threads in the system have terminated.

The JVM can terminate when Daemon threads are running in it. Since daemon threads are usually used for *clean up* tasks, it makes little sense to keep JVM alive when only daemon threads are running.